# Animation android start immediately

Tags: android, animation, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm doing the following simple animation in Android:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:duration="2000"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"/>
```

I call the animation like this:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus) {
    if (hasFocus) {
        tvload.startAnimation(anim);
    }
}
```

The animation starts immediately in pre-lollipop devices but in lollipop and Marshmallow it takes around 1 sec for it to start. This animation should start after intent.

Is there a way to make this animation start immediately instead of having the 1 second load time?

Answer (score 0):

I would give the [View#post()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)) method a try.  It will run the code you post next UI thread cycle which is *usually* as soon as the View is visible.

```
tvload.post(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
     tvload.startAnimation(anim);
  }
};
```

Comment: I tried it and doesn't work, it takes some seconds too, thanks!